# how can i remove "\n" in string in php?

Tags: php

how to remove "\n" in string?
I used 3 method bellow ,seams that only the "\s+" works , but I only want to remove \n,not all space ,how to do the job?
need help, this question had puzzled me for a long time.

```
$str="<p>
    hello<br>
    world
</p>";

//$str=str_replace("\n","",$str);
$str=preg_replace("@\n@","",$str);
//$str=preg_replace("@\s+@"," ",$str);  
echo $str;
```

Comment: try with [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should also do the trick.

```
$str=str_replace("\r\n","",$str);
```

Comment: good，this is what I want ,thank you

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Notice if is a linux/unix system it should be str_replace("\n","",$str);

Comment: $str=str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",$str));

Answer (score 26):

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

The above code will replace multiple spaces and newlines with a single space.

Comment: This one worked for me when I was trying to strip new lines in an HTML string. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot.